# Large Rasters in ArcGIS & MapInfo

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mapinfo, erdas-imagine

My geoscientists like to work with MapInfo and ArcGIS. I require a common 1 band raster format that can hold obscene amounts of data without damaging the data (compression). I have tried .tif and found it to be rather unhappy once it's starts to gain a few GB. I'm now inclined to move to .ers Question 1: **What universal analytical raster is best**?

In this particular case we have CSIRO file geodatabase rasters (around 7GB uncompressed). I can not see them directly with: ERDAS ER Mapper, or ERDAS Imagine, nor MapInfo Professional 12.5+ (with the fgdb api). Therefore I need to bring them out to an intermediate raster so I can export them to .ers or ecw with ERDAS.  Question 2: **What intermediate raster is best**?

So far ArcGIS exports to massive .tif has failed as a universal analytic raster and intermediate raster. I'm now testing the Esri grid. Does anyone have good advice?

Comment: Slice it and keep as mosaic

Comment: Yeah I thought about sub-setting it (even as an intermediate). But that does not suit the geoscientists.

Comment: I haven't tried it and can't find much information about its compatibility with other products - but [ArcGIS Server's Image extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions/image-extension) might be worth researching further

Comment: Erdas IMG is my *lowest common denominator*: huge file limits, single or many multiple bands (more than 4), data types from 1 bit to 64bit per band, read by ArcGis, Global Mapper, GDAL - hence QGIS, TNTmips... even ERDAS. Compression is none or RLE so values are unchanged. Unlike TIFF the tags haven't been invaded by photo-enthusiasts and patched-up to suit 4GB+ (BigTIFF) and supports a *true* NoData value (GeoTiff doesn't have a true NoData tag). If that doesn't work BIL may be the only 'true' source but that has display issues in ArcGis.

Comment: Note: if you find that an ERDAS Imagine file is getting too big and filling up your file system you can compress the folder that it's in for a space saving without affecting the pixel values - being almost totally uncompressed they pack/zip very well with even the basic windows file compressor.

Comment: I've worked with terabyte+ sized GeoTIFFs before. Please expand on why you think they get unhappy :(... What issues did you have? Did you use compression? Did you ensure they were saved in "BIGTIFF" format? How were you creating them?

Comment: The biggest problem I've had with TIFF/GeoTIFF/BigTIFF is with tags that some software has issues with whist others cope or ignore.. The non-existence of a NoData tag is just one example (most software respects the GDALNODATA tag as proxy, but not all) and spatial reference embedding are a few of the big ones. There is no guarantee that a TIFF file (irrespective of size) will be readable by all GIS packages... then there's compression, LZ77 is used by Esri but some software doesn't understand it... @Luke, if you keep it to Arc you wont have a problem until you want to share it around.

Comment: @Luke I'm glad you can work with raster in the terabytes. Are they working across ArcGIS and MapInfo? Method: Using the ArcGIS Desktop 10.1. GUI context menu, I export the file geodatabase raster to <Name>.tif file. The environment settings were unchanged from the defaults. The tiff file is 7.48GB with LZW compression and is 32bit floating point. 
ArcGIS Desktop 10.1: Once the pyramids are generated, it’s viewable. For MapInfo Professional Discover 2011: it errors: "Not a Tiff file, bad version number 43 (0x2b)... and: Raster engine was unable to recognize format..."

Comment: @GISI I doubt you'll be able to get MapInfo Pro/Discover to read 32bit GeoTIFF files. It's the 32bit that is causing MapInfo Pro problems. We aren't supporting these until we release the 64bit MapInfo Pro Raster add-on within the next month and Discover won't have this capability until later this year when the 64bit release is ready. Currently I would recommend the ERMapper Grid (ers) or maybe the GeoSoft (grd) format. But to be honest I haven't worked with 10+ GB files in these formats yet

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller Yes. I aim to use .ers as our universal raster. I've exported the fGDB raster to esri grid and .tif (with defaults) then failed to open them with ERDAS: it reports the compression is "unsupported". I will play with the compression then.

Comment: @GISI I don't use MapInfo. The rasters were created with GDAL and were readable in ArcGIS, ERDAS Imagine and ENVI software (though ENVI doesn't recognise one of the available lossless compression methods, can't remember which one, so I used one of the other methods).

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question but, in any event, now 18 months down the track if the question is to stay open with no answers I think you need to revise it in light of the advice offered as comments.